# How to use Compose Accompanist to work with new permissions on old devices?

Tags: android, permissions, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack, jetpack-compose-accompanist

Using Jetpack Compose Permissions from the Accompanist Permission library (https://google.github.io/accompanist/permissions/) is a nice reactive way. However, it's unclear to me how to deal with permissions which depend on the OS version its being used on.

For instance, the opt-out for notification changed with Android Tiramisu/33 så that it's now opt-in using POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission. The question then is, how do you use

```
val permissionState: PermissionState = rememberPermissionState(
        permission = Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS
    )
```

...when the POST_NOTIFICATIONS API can't be referenced on say Android 9. The only workaround I can think of, which feels like a hack, is to fall-back to some other permission which is auto-granted by default i.e. the INTERNET permission. Like so:

```
val permissionState: PermissionState = rememberPermissionState(
        permission = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
            Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS else Manifest.permission.INTERNET
    )
```

Is there a better solution than the one mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better workaround:

```
 val permissionState = rememberMultiplePermissionsState(
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
        listOf(Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS)
    } else {
        // permission not needed
        emptyList()
    }
 )
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative solution Derek. Both solutions appears to work in practice, the main difference being whether you want to use PermissionState or MultiplePermissionsState - the latter being slightly more complex revolving around a (non-existing) set rather than a single (potentially no-op) PermissionStatus.